# Основная задача Hardware Description Language (HDL)

Tags: железо

Читая 'The Elements of Computing Systems: Building a Modern Computer from First Principles' не совсем понял суть HDL. Это язык (к примеру Verilog), который просто и понятно для человека описывает конкретные логические части аппаратуры, или же он предназначен для исполнения уже в 'железе', как уровень абстракции?

Answer (score 0):

Изначально языки описания аппаратуры использовались просто для документирования и моделированя реальных схем, но с появлением [логического синтеза](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B7) эти языки стали применяться уже *создания* цифровых схем.

Например, такие устройства как FPGA программируются преимущественно на HDL: архитектура уровня логических вентилей *синтезируются* из исходного кода на HDL и затем уже применяется для перепрограммирования реального устройства.

Так что, грубо говоря, вы правы, говоря, что описания на HDL предназначены для исполнения железом. Более правильно было бы сказать, что эти описания с помощью логического синтеза *превращаются* в само железо.

Comment: А нужны он, как я понял, для того, что бы каждый раз физически не собирать схему, просто запрограммировать уже собранный набор элементов под нужный виртуальный аналог?

Comment: @DestryX, я не совсем понял последнюю часть вопроса. HDL нужны для описания аппаратуры. Все. Как потом это описание будет применяться  — вопрос уже другой. Это описание (на языке HDL) могут синтезировать в готовую цифровую схему, могут использовать как документацию, могут использовать для моделирования на компьютере... Никто не мешает просто вручную нарисовать схему, но HDL позволяют перейти на более высокий уровень абстракций, что *значительно* упрощает разработку сложных проектов.